# glXCreateContextAttribsARB: fb config compatibility

Tags: opengl, configuration, framebuffer, openglcontext

OpenGL doc states that

> If glXCreateContextAttribsARB succeeds, it initializes the context to
>   the initial state defined by the OpenGL specification, and returns a
>   handle to it. This handle can be used to render to any GLX surface
>   (window, pixmap, or pbuffer) compatible with `<config>`, subject to
>   constraints imposed by the OpenGL API version of the context.

How do I determine compatibility of different framebuffer configurations?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I determine compatibility of different framebuffer configurations?

By creating the drawable (window, pixmap, pbuffer) using that framebuffer configuration. This is not something you query  but you define at drawable creation time.